# How do I install JDK 8 with NetBeans(Cobundle) on 16.04 Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, netbeans

So I went to the official Java site and downloaded a JDK 8 with NetBeans  with .sh extension and it opens with a text editor and I have no idea what to do with it. I've opened it with gedit and at the top of screen is says it is loading that pack but its going really, really, REALLY slow. I just don't know if that is supposed to go that slow or am I doing something wrong. I apologize in advance for my stupidity, be patient with me, I love you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Change the current directory path where you have downloaded the `.sh` file in terminal using following command

   `cd path/to/downloaded-file`
3. Take Read/Write/Execute permission by typing following command in terminal for the downloaded `.sh` file

   `sudo chmod 777 downloaded-file.sh`
4. Run the file by

   `./downloaded-file.sh`

Done!

Answer (score 0):

The above method described by Shivam Satija is correct but if you come across the module error while building up your java application then follow the below mentioned steps:

1. Open `netbeans.conf` file under `netbeans/etc/` folder
2. Change the `"netbeans_jdkhome"` path
   usually it is `netbeans_jdkhome="/usr"` 
   you have to change it to `netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"`

voila

**Note:** I have java-8-openjdk-amd64 installed but you may have some other So point to that folder